# UX,как сделать правильно?

Tags: css, css3, веб-дизайн, ux

Итак, есть страница с дефолтными записями (скажем с товарами для удобства)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть кнопка фильтров и поле поиска.
Фильтрация происходит AJAX запросом на бэк, и далее результат выводится в таблицу. Поиск аналогично.

Если ввести в поле поиска запрос, то поиск происходит по всей базе, товарам.
Но если выбрать фильтры, например фильтры цвета: красный и синий, в таблицу запросом выводятся только товары соответствующие фильтру. Скажем iphone 11 и iphone 22. Тогда если ввести в поле поиска запрос, то как он должен искать, по всей базе или же с учетом выбранных фильтров ?

Возможно будет лучше сделать так: если **не** выбраны фильтры, то искать по всей базе, а если **выбраны**, то искать с их учетом. И наоборот, если в поле ввести например samsung и далее при выборе фильтров, сортировать только среди самсунгов ?
Будет ли такой вариант удобен и правильный с точки зрения UX ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `..по всей базе или же с учетом выбранных фильтров..` этим должна заниматься бэк сторона, фронт только соберёт нужный фильтр и отправит его на сервер.

Comment: @De.Minov да, но вопрос был в другом, какой вариант более удобен в пользовании, ux

Comment: @Jesse Не думаю, что тут можно получить объективный ответ. Вам бы к дизайнерам обращаться с такими вопросами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На правах ИМХО:

Как тестировщик, в том числе и UI, считаю, что возможны оба варианта, но прежде всего надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь однозначно избежал путаницы.

Вариант 1:
поиск идет по всей базе, а фильтры - отдельная песня. Так реализовано в большинстве интернет-магазинов, например. При этом форма поиска вынесена, скажем, в хедер и не создается впечатления, что он и кнопка фильтров равноправны. Минус такого решения - результаты поиска надо фильтровать отдельно (если такой возможности нет, это бесит - а таким грешат даже серьезные магазины).

Вариант 2: поиск по базе идет с учетом уже примененных фильтров. По факту это даже не поиск, а дополнительная фильтрация по прочим полям (название/описание/и т.д.). Следствие из этого факта: вместо формы поиска лучше разворачивать форму расширенной фильтрации.

Бонус-вариант 3: сделать и расширенную фильтрацию, и общий поиск по варианту 1.

Comment: Отлично, 3 вариант в моем случае подойдет. Спасибо!